# How do I reverse the playback of an animation (instead of restarting it)?

Tags: c++, directx11

I have created a sprite sheet of which consists of six frames of a character whose legs move each frame. Now I have written code so that the animation is running successfully from frame one to frame six, however I am trying to *reverse* this so then instead of looping back to frame one after the last frame, the animation moves backwards from frame six to frame one and then repeats in a continuous loop.

I handle the animation currently like this:

```
void SpriteGame::Update(int tickTotal, int tickDelta)
{
    if ( tickTotal >= this->playerLastFrameChange + 4)
    {
        //Four ticks have elapsed since the last frame change
        this->playerFrame = this->playerFrame + 1;
        this->playerLastFrameChange = tickTotal;  //We've just changed the frame 

        if (this->playerFrame >= this->playerSheetLength)
        {
            this->playerFrame = playerLastFrameChange + 4;
        }

        //Frame has changed so change the source rectangle
        this->playerSourceRect->left = this->playerFrame * 64;    
        this->playerSourceRect->top = 0;     
        this->playerSourceRect->right = (this->playerFrame + 1) * 64;  
        this->playerSourceRect->bottom = 64; 
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this using Direct3D 11?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool forward=true;

( tickTotal >= this->playerLastFrameChange + 4){
//Four ticks have elapsed since the last frame change
 if(forward)
  this->playerFrame = this->playerFrame + 1;
 else
  this->playerFrame = this->playerFrame - 1;
}
```

Just add a boolean indicating which direction you are currently moving in. Depending on this you in- or decrease the current frame. 
You need to set the boolean to false, after you reached the last frame (to move back again) and to true after you reached the first frame again.

This will oscillate between back and foreward

Comment: Rather than a bool and an if-check it's even easier and mildly more efficient (less branching) to just use a `float` time scalar.  To play forward set it to `1.0`.  To play forward in double speed set it to `2.0`.  To play backward, set it to `-1.0`.  Backward in half speed is `-0.5`.  To pause, set to `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

A more general way to handle this would be to insert an abstraction layer between the animation and the frames of the animation on your sprite sheet.

Right now, you are just assuming that an animation consists of the sequential playback of frames 1 through frame *N* of some sprite sheet, and now you'd like to change that to the meaning is "frames 1 through *N*, and then frames *N - 1* through 1 in reverse." floAr's answer (introduce a variable indicating whether the animation is traversing frames forward or backwards) is perfectly acceptable and will do exactly what you want.

What I propose is a more generalized approach where an animation is a list of *arbitrary* frame numbers from the sprite sheet (instead of the implicit sequential list you are currently working with). This requires additional data and as such as a slight overhead in terms of memory and content creation time.

To accomplish this, you'd read the list of frames (which I will call an "animation sequence") from a data file (which can be as simple as a text file), which might look like this:

```
//walk_animation.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

This file (`walk_animation.txt`) defines each frame of the animation, space-separated, as a number which refers to a sprite index in the sprite sheet. Frames 1 through 6 of the animation correspond exactly to sprites 1 through 6 in the sheet, but frame 7 of the animation is sprite 5, 8 is 4, and so on.

At the cost of some additional data overhead, this approach allows you keep your current, simple animation code (that just loops the animation). It also affords you the flexibility of using an entire sprite sheet for potentially many distinct animations, and easily having variants of an animation (for example a "fast" and "slow" punching animation, whether the "fast" animation omits some less-than-critical frames).